# copying a table across servers with psycopg3

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg3

I'm working from and example in the psycopg3 documentation to copy a table from one database to another: [link](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#example-copying-a-table-across-servers)

```py
dsn_src = 'postgresql:///dev_db'
dsn_tgt = 'postgresql:///prod_test'

with psycopg.connect(dsn_src) as conn1, psycopg.connect(dsn_tgt) as conn2:
    with conn1.cursor().copy("COPY sample TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy1:
        with conn2.cursor().copy("COPY sample FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy2:
            for data in copy1:
                copy2.write(data)
```

running this results in the following error

```
QueryCanceled: COPY from stdin failed: error from Python: TypeError - can't write memoryview
CONTEXT:  COPY sample, line 1
```

The source and target schema are identical, as the documentation recommends, and this error persists if the format specification `(FORMAT BINARY)` is removed.

Is there are way to resolve this `memoryview` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing you are using `psycopg3` <= 3.0.11. This was fixed in 3.0.12 per [Release Notes](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/news.html). I ran the code in 3.0.11 and it failed as you showed. I upgraded to 3.0.13 and it worked.